# Showing objects count in list

Tags: c#, list

I have a list `List<IVehicle> vehicles = new List<IVehicle>();` and in that list I want to store objects (`Car`, `Boat`, `Mc`) that implement `IVehicle`.

How can I print out how many objects of ex car I have in the list?

I tried using LINQ `int count = vehicles.Count(x => x == car);` but it does now count correct.

Comment: I'm assuming Car, Boat, Mc are _types_, that _implement_ `IVehicle`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming all your Car,Boat,Mc objects implement `IVehicle`:

You can achieve this by using `OfType<T>` method which is LINQ extension method.

```
int count = vehicles.OfType<Car>().Count();
```

`OfType<T>` method as stated by Microsoft document:

> Filters the elements of an IEnumerable based on a specified type.

Answer (score 3):

In this line:

```
int count = vehicles.Count(x => x == car);
```

It is not clear what `car` is.
If is it a specific object of type `Car` you will get the number of elements that are equal to that object.

But anyway if you want to count all elements which are instances of **type** `Car`s you need:

```
//------------------------------vvvvvvvv--
int count = vehicles.Count(x => x is Car);
```

Note the usage of the [**is operator**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#is-operator) to check if an object is of a specific type.

Comment: I'd also recommend doing the comparison using `.GetType()`, because that will be useful to know should you need to use `.GroupBy()` for getting stats on _all_ types.

Comment: I agree it's more general. But I find using the `is` operator more simple and straightforward in this specific case. In any case using `.GetType()` is demonstrated in the other answer.